# How to use Apache Ant in Jmeter?

Tags: ant, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

How to generate Html reports from using Apache ant in Jmeter.
`Please attach screenshots`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There won't be too much screenshots, however I believe the answer will still be helpful

1. Install [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/). Make sure that /bin folder of Ant installation is in your PATH
2. Go to "extras" folder of your JMeter installation in command propmt.
3. Type `ant`
4. If everything goes well you should see "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" message

   [image: Ant execution]
5. Ant will generate 2 artifacts:

   - Test.jtl - XML file with results
   - Test.html - HTML wile with results which can be viewed in browser

   [image: Ant resutls]
6. If steps 1-5 are successful you can now replace /extras/Test.jmx with your own JMeter test, delete `Test.jtl` file and execute step 3 for your test script.

See following references:

- `/extras/build.xml` Ant build file
- [JMeter Ant Task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/) manual
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide which includes launching JMeter via Ant.

Comment: i copied  all Apache Ant files from bin ( apache-ant-1.9.6\bin ) and paste to " apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\extras " , above commands in screenshots not work for me. Please explain clearly , i am beginner in jmeter .

Comment: It won't work that way. Ant is a separate tool. Just make sure that ant.bat script is in your OS PATH

Comment: @DmitriT, Can we do "Generating Report Dashboard" through ANT? Talking about the data in the below link http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter produces the result in XML format. You need an XSLT file to convert this to a nice HTML.

This site has the detailed steps on running JMeter tests with ANT + creating HTML reports + Creating charts.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-continuous-performance-testing-part1/